# Show error bars in ColumnSeries of LiveCharts (LvCharts) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, errorbar, livecharts

I am using LiveCharts (LvCharts) for VB.NET (WPF) and I am showing values as bar series in different charts in my GUI (series type = LiveCharts.Geared.GColumnSeries).

Currently I am searching for a way to show error bars in my series (show standard deviation or min/max values) like this example:

[image: Columkn series with error bars]

Unfortunately I didn't found any example for that. I already checked:

- https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/tree/master/Examples/Wpf
- https://v0.lvcharts.com/App/examples/Wpf/start

How could I realize that with LvCharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already supported in the latest version:

https://livecharts.dev/docs/WPF/2.0.0-rc2/samples.error.basic

Comment: Thank's for the information! We are using LiveCharts Geared commercial version and it is already implemented in several projects. How complex is the migration from v1 to v2? And can I use geared values in v2?

Comment: @krambambuli there is no direct migration from v0 to v2, but the API is similar, v2 will also have a high-performance package, it is extremely fast, you can find some tests here: https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc2

Comment: It seemed to be difficult to change from v0 to v2 in a running project. I have to change a lot of functions, also in the xaml code. Especially because I was using geared values. Or am I wrong @bto.rdz?